# cycles compute device shows as "none"

Tags: gpu

i  had graphic card of  nividia gforce210 but while I want to enable gpu in cycle render then it show the "none" in cycle computer device please help me.

Comment: yah, a 210 is rather old. I doubt cycles still supports it.

Comment: see how old is this card https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=GeForce+210 even if current cycles supported it, you won't get fast results anyway...

Comment: The english version of the link in the first comment. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA